# Regex to replace subset of repeated pattern

Tags: regular-expressions, replace

```
ABC、DEF, GHI, JKL、MNO
PQR、STU, VWX、YZ
```

How do I replace all `,` s with `、` in the repeated pattern above?

The repeated pattern can be mapped with the regex below:

```elisp
"^\\([A-Z]+、\\)\\(\\([A-Z]+\\), \\)+"
```

However, because the `,`  is a subset of group `\\2`, even though it can be separated from its preceding letters in the regex,

[image]

there is no way to replace it using `replace-regexp` without some form of nested group code. Also, `DEF,`  doesn't seem the match like `GHI,`  and `STU,`  with the regex.

```elisp
(replace-regexp "^\\([A-Z]+、\\)\\(\\([A-Z]+\\), \\)+" "\\1\\2、")
```

What's the right way to do this, then?

---

## Update:

@jue's answer below resulted in this:

[image: failed result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In elisp you normally search for what you're looking for in a loop, potentially establishing sub-groups of interest, and then you act on the match data if the search succeeded.  Here you can simply replace every `,` with `、` within the subgroup.

```el
(save-excursion
  (while (re-search-forward "^[A-Z]+、\\(\\(?:[A-Z]+, \\)+\\)" nil t)
    (goto-char (match-beginning 1))
    (let ((bound (match-end 1)))
      (while (search-forward "," bound t)
        (replace-match "、")))))
```

Edit: Or more simply:

```el
(save-excursion
  (while (re-search-forward "^[A-Z]+、" nil t)
    (while (re-search-forward "\\=\\([A-Z]+\\), " nil t)
      (replace-match "\\1、 "))))
```

That `\=` construct anchors the match to the current position of point, so that only the intended sequence of cases will be matched for that loop.  Other options are supplying a BOUND argument to the search, or using narrowing to temporarily limit the searchable text.

---

> Also, DEF, doesn't seem the match like GHI, and STU, with the regex.

That's because re-builder was highlighting the text which was referred to by back-reference `\2` (being the ultimate match for that repeated subgroup) differently to the rest of the text.  Try adding more matches for that group in a line, and it will become more obvious.

Comment: What if there are commas behind `PQR、STU, VWX、YZ` which I do not want to touch? For this is a simplification of Chinese bibliographic citations, APA style. A full citation looks like this: `鄧天珍、史少華, 白云星、方北松 (2019). 玉門花海畢家灘棺板《晉律注》保護修復. 江漢考古, (S1), 26–30.` , which roughly translates to `PQR、STU, VWX、YZ (2019). Title. Journal, (issue), 26-30.`

Comment: My answer was based on the case in your question.  If you want to make more detailed replacements then the inner `(while (search-forward ...` might be a `(while (re-search-forward` with a more detailed search pattern, and you might be specifying a group in the `replace-match` call.  As always in Emacs, read the help for the functions in question, or look them up in the manual.

Comment: I've added a simpler approach with a nested regexp search.